# Square root in $\mathbb{Z}_p{}^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Given a prime $q$, and another prime $p$ = 20q + 1, I am able to find generators in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Does $-1$ have a square root in $\mathbb{Z}_p{}^*$? 
Thanks!

Comment: You mean $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ right?

Comment: There are 20q elements in Zp*

Comment: For all x in Zp, gcd(x, p) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: If $p$ is prime, ${\bf Z}_p^*$ is a cyclic group.